# Select TagHelper Using List from ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am currently trying to use taghelpers in asp.net 5.  I want to use a select tag helper with a list from the ViewBag.   Anything I put into the asp-for field gives me an error because it tries to pull it from the model which is IEnumerable instead of the view bag.

I want to replace this:

```
@model IEnumerable<InvoiceIT.Models.Invoice>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>            
        @Html.DropDownList("Companies", String.Empty)       
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default" />
    </p>
}
```

with this:

```
@model IEnumerable<InvoiceIT.Models.Invoice>
<form asp-controller="Invoice" asp-action="Index" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <select asp-for="????" asp-items="ViewBag.Companies" class="form-control">
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

Here is how I populate the select list in the controller:

```
ViewBag.Companies = new SelectList(await DbContext.Company.ToListAsync(), "CompanyID", "Name");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want the `asp-for` attribute to pull from the `Model` directly you can override that behavior by providing an `@`.

Aka:

```
<select asp-for="@ViewBag.XYZ">
    ...
</select>
```

Therefore, based on what you said I believe your bit becomes:

```
@model IEnumerable<InvoiceIT.Models.Invoice>
<form asp-controller="Invoice" asp-action="Index" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
@{
    SelectList companies = ViewBag.Companies;
    var currentlySelectedIndex = 0; // Currently selected index (usually will come from model)
}
    <select asp-for="@currentlySelectedIndex" asp-items="companies" class="form-control">
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
</form>
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Using your exact code I get a compile error on the asp-for field: 'an expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation'.

Comment: Ahh, good point. Updated response to reflect the proper usage (see added bits inside `@{ }`).

Comment: This seems to be getting closer as it compiles however it adds a listbox type control instead of a drop down, and it is empty of data.  If I change it to `asp-for="@companies" asp-items="@ViewBag.Companies"`  then I get the same listbox but it has the correct data in it.  How do I get a dropdown instead?

Comment: Sorry @Reafidy, I responded wayyy too quickly and fat fingered a few things. Updated the answer to reflect the proper usage.  

As for details as to why it works. IF the value provided to `asp-for` happens to be an `IEnumerable` (and not a `string`) then it wont render as a dropdown list. Otherwise it will :)

Comment: Thanks, that works,  it's now become a lot more long winded than just using the old fashioned: `@Html.DropDownList`

Comment: @N.TaylorMullen I spent lots of time figuring out a solution where I could use ViewBag to fill in the `Select Tag Helper` in a view while using @model directive in the same view for something else. Your solution helped me achieve such  a task - thank you for helping.

Answer (score 3):

asp-for just needs to be the property with the current selected value and asp-items needs to be an

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
```

this snippet is from working code in my project:

```
<select id="CompanyCountry" asp-for="CompanyCountry"
           asp-items="Model.AvailableCountries" class="form-control"></select>
```

in my model I'm using

```
IList<SelectListItem>
```

for AvailableCountries

Comment: so for your example looks like ViewBag.CompanyID should be on asp-for and asp-items should be the list of selectlist items representing companies

Comment: Hey Joe,  I have updated the question.   When I place companyID in the asp-for field I get an error: 'IEnumerable<Invoice> does not contain a definition for companyID'.  I believe this is because I am trying to use the viewbag as a source and companyid only exists in the viewbag source and not in the model.

Comment: did you try using @ViewBag.companyID? I do think asp-for is for model binding whereas viewbag is for display. asp-for should be a property of the model that contains a value that corresponds to a value in the selectlistitems. the idea is on get the current value for the property will be selected, if the user selects a different value and submits the form, the new selected value will be bound to the model property automatically for you on post of the form so you can save the model with the new selected value

Comment: Yes I did and I get a compile error:  'an expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation'.  The select list I want to use is a filter drop-down for the pages table.  It has nothing to do with editing the model so companyid is not suppose to be in the model.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to set asp-for at all in that scenario, just asp-items.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this ...

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id_TourCategory, new SelectList(ViewBag.TourCate, "Value", "Text"))

 public ActionResult TourPackage()
    {
        List<TourCategory> lst = new List<TourCategory>();
        lst = db.TourCategories.ToList();
        ViewBag.TourCate = new SelectList(lst, "Id", "CategoryName");          
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Umm thanks but the code I have works for a DropDownList, the point is I am trying to use a taghelper.