# MVC Add employee to the group

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I made a small website where you can manage employees. There are groups who can work on a Task. I made the Groups and Task and Employees but now my problem is, that the group is empty at start. I made a button to add employees to the group. The group has an Employee list which needs to be populated.

I created the AddEmployee.cshtml but I get an error for

```
<label asp-for="Employees" class="control-label"></label>
<select asp-for="Employees" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.Employees"></select>
```

Error   CS1061  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Employees' and no accessible extension method 'Employees' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable' could be found.

Here is my code snippet from the controller:

```
public IActionResult AddEmployee()
        {
            ViewData["Employees"] = new SelectList(_context.Employees, "Employees", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee([Bind("GroupId,Name,Employees")] Group group)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Groups.Add(group);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["Employees"] = new SelectList(_context.Employees, "Employees", "Name", group.Employees);
            return View(group);
        }
```

Comment: You really should stop using ViewData/ViewBag to pass data around. Use the Model, it's strongly typed and will result in less errors. If you find yourself needing to use ViewData, then just assume you're doing it wrong and need to use Model instead.

Comment: Could you provide me a solution with either ViewData or Model? Or point me where is the problem?

Comment: Switch everything to use Model. Eliminate ViewBag/ViewData. You'll likely fix your issue in the process.

Comment: You should use the model, as mentioned, but if you insist on ViewData, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804462/select-taghelper-using-list-from-viewbag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select TagHelper Using List from ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804462/select-taghelper-using-list-from-viewbag)